# in Citadels, the Fort card ability does it affect whole city or just the card?

Tags: citadels

The Fort card ability makes it immune to the tier 8 character ability. Does it apply to the whole city or just to the Fort?

It might be that the Fort ability is unclear in my language edition.

Comment: Welcome to Board and card games. The question is a bit hard to understand. Can you please edit the question and add some more information.

Comment: I wonder, what does it say in your language then? Like Eric Nolan's answer says, it's rather clear in the English text, and it's similar in the other translations I saw on boardgamegeek.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are referring to the Keep card as it is called in the English edition the text is quite clear that only that specific building is protected.

[image: Keep card from Citadels 2016]